# Opa: What Is the Fastest Way to Reverse a String?

Tags: recursion, opa

What is the most performant way to implement a "reverse a string" function in Opa?

I am aware of `String.reverse()`. It does get the job done, but its source code is bound to some external function. I want to understand what the best (fastest) tools are for reordering a string.

So, for example, this works, but isn't particularly fast:

```
reverse(s:string) =
  p = parser
    | x=(.) xs=(.*) -> Text.concat(reverse(Text.to_string(xs)), x)
    | x=(.*) -> x
  Parser.parse(p, s)
```

How can I make this perform better?

#### Edit: Another Implementation Based on akoprowski's Answer

I think this is what he has in mind. This one is much faster than the parser version, but the built-in `String.reverse` is the way to go if all you need to do is reverse a string.

```
reverse_list(l:list(string)):list(string) =
  match l with
  | [x|xs] -> reverse_list(xs) ++ [x]
  | _ -> []

reverse_string(s:string) =
  string_list = List.init((i -> String.get(i, s)), String.length(s))
  String.flatten(reverse_list(string_list))
```

#### Edit: The Above Implementation Is Not Ideal

Check out the accepted answer for a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to use `String.reverse`? (which *is* the preferred way of reversing a string). Or is that just an exercise?

I'd suggest using [`List.init`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.list.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.List.init) to generate a list of characters, [`String.get`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.string.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.String.get) (to get n'th character of the string) and [`String.flatten`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.string.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.String.flatten) to convert a list of characters back to a string.

That should be faster than the parsing-based approach, which btw. has quadratic complexity so no wonder it's slow.

**Edit**: the solution I had in mind:

```
reverse_string(s:string) =
  n = String.length(s)
  rev_list = List.init((i -> String.get(n - i - 1, s)), n)
  String.flatten(rev_list)
```

Comment: Ack. I'll avoid the parsing option. It is, in fact, just an exercise. I have more complex string operations I'd like to implement, and reversing a string is similar enough to be a good learning tool. How does the built-in `String.reverse` work? Is it implemented in Opa? OCaml? In the source of `stdlib/core/string.opa`, I get lost at `reverse = %% BslString.reverse %%`.

Comment: I added another implementation. Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Not quite:
(1) You should use `List.rev` for list reversal as it is linear, whereas your `reverse_list` is quadratic (as you're using append); plus `List.rev` is tail-recursive
(2) Instead of reversing the list you can immediately construct it with the proper order in place; see my solution.

Comment: I'm noticing that I like to build functions with quadratic complexity. :P Thanks for guiding me to solutions with mere linear complexity. :)